# Multiple database queries strung together

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am attempting to put some form data into two database tables, using the following logic

- `INSERT` new Watchlist to `'watchlists'` table
- `SELECT watchlist_id` of new Watchlist from `'watchlists'` table `WHERE watchlist_name = $watchlist_name` (name of new Watchlist just created) and `user_id = $user_id`
- `INSERT watchlist_id` (selected from previous query) AND `film_id` into `'watchlist_films'` table

I am using the following code, but the process seems to break while running the `SELECT` query. THe new Watchlist is created in the database fine, but it won't select the ID of the new Watchlist, or run the final section of the code.

```
if ($db_server) {
        // Add new Watchlisth
        if (!empty($watchlist_name)) {
            $watchlist_name = clean_string($watchlist_name);
            $watchlist_description = clean_string($watchlist_description);
            mysql_select_db($db_database);

            // Create new Watchlist
            $insert_new_watchlist = "INSERT INTO watchlists (user_id, name, description, category) VALUES ('$user_id', '$watchlist_name', '$watchlist_description', '$watchlist_category')";
            mysql_query($insert_new_watchlist) or die("Insert failed. " . mysql_error() . "<br />" . $insert_new_watchlist);

            // Select new Watchlist's ID
            $select_new_watchlist_query = "SELECT watchlist_id FROM watchlists WHERE name = " . $watchlist_name;
            $new_watchlist_id = mysql_query($select_new_watchlist_query);

            // Insert film into new Watchlist
            $add_new_film = "INSERT INTO watchlist_films (watchlist_id, film_id) VALUES ('$new_watchlist_id', '$rt_id')";
            mysql_query($add_new_film) or die("Insert failed. " . mysql_error() . "<br />" . $add_new_film);
            $addWatchlist_good_message = '<div class="alert alert-success">Watchlist created successfully, and film added!</div>';?>
            <script>
                $('a.add-watchlist').trigger('click');
            </script><?php
        }
    } else {
        $addWatchlist_bad_message = '<div class="alert alert-error">Error: could not connect to the database.</div.';?>
        <script>
            $('a.add-watchlist').trigger('click');
        </script><?php
    }
    require_once("db_close.php");
}
```

I have run the query in phpMyAdmin using the following string: `SELECT watchlist_id FROM watchlists where name = "LotR"` (where LotR is the name of the newly created Watchlist) and that works perfectly, insofar as it brings me back the Watchlist's ID, which is what I want to pass into the second of the two `INSERT` queries.

Comment: Don't use the mysql_query syntax, It's deprecated, and use prepared statements (You'r asking us to inject code into your database). I commend using PDO. You can find many working examples on my profile that will solve your problem within 10 minutes. Or just google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_query()` returns a *resource* data type, not a field value, so replace

```
$new_watchlist_id = mysql_query($select_new_watchlist_query);
```

with

```
$result=mysql_query($select_new_watchlist_query);
$new_watchlist_id=mysql_result($result,0)
```